# ActiveModel dirty to ignore milliseconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I make ActiveModel::Dirty ignore milliseconds when comparing datetime in Rails.

```
     news.publish_at
     => Fri, 16 Nov 2018 17:05:37 CET +01:00

     news.publish_at = news.publish_at.to_s
     => "2018-11-16 17:05:37 +0100"

     news.publish_at_changed?
     => true
```

But if I add milliseconds to the above datetime, changed? is false.

```
     news.publish_at = "2018-11-16 17:05:37.517 +0100"
     => "2018-11-16 17:05:37.517 +0100"

     news.publish_at_changed?
     => false
```

I am using Rails 5.2.1

Comment: Did you consider removing the milliseconds automatically when assigning a datetime to `publish_at`?

Comment: @spickermann I tried that and seems to work fine. Could you add that as the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest workaround might be to just add a custom setter to that model that truncates the milliseconds everytime when assigning a new value.

```
def publish_at=(value)
  if value
    time_without_usec = DateTime.parse(value).change(usec: 0)
    value = time_without_usec.to_s
  end

  super(value)
end
```